# UI blocks while pushing view controller on to navigation controller

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface, uiviewcontroller

I have just moved my iOS 5 project to iOS 6 environment (since Apple made it mandatory to support 4-inch device compability) and now I am having a bit of a problem while pushing a `UIViewController` on to `UINavigationController`.

After I push my custom `UIViewController`, my user interface blocks for 5 to 20 seconds, only when I am pushing that custom `UIViewController` for the first time. If I pop my `UIViewController` and push it again, there is no delay or UI block.

Here is what happens;

First I am pushing my UIViewController from UITableViewController's didSelectRowAtIndexPath (custom init works fine, no issue there)

```
CampaignDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[CampaignDetailViewController alloc] initWithProduct:selectedProduct];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

Than I am logging everything (I cleared all code in `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`, which means pushing the controller should only load nib)

On the pushed `UIViewController`;

```
- (id)initWithProduct:(Product *)selectedProduct
{
    NSLog(@"starting init");
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"CampaignDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    NSLog(@"nib loaded");
    if (self) {
        self.navigationItem.title = selectedProduct.name;
        self.product = selectedProduct;
    }
    NSLog(@"finishing init");
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"starting viewdidload");
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"finishing viewdidload");
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"view will appear");
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"view did appear");
}
```

**Debugger Log;**

```
2013-05-03 12:33:49.678 my-app[1429:707] starting init
2013-05-03 12:33:49.680 my-app[1429:707] nib loaded
2013-05-03 12:33:49.683 my-app[1429:707] finishing init
2013-05-03 12:33:49.808 my-app[1429:707] starting viewdidload
2013-05-03 12:33:49.855 my-app[1429:707] finishing viewdidload
2013-05-03 12:33:49.861 my-app[1429:707] view will appear
2013-05-03 12:35:28.501 my-app[1429:707] view did appear
```

There is over 30 seconds of delay between viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear.

**Further Info**

- I have tried to use regular `init` and removed the nib file, nothing changed.
- Nothing gets loaded in between of pushViewController and loading the UIViewController.
- This issue happens on my iPhone 4 - iOS 5 device. Everything works fine on iOS 5 and 6 simulators also works fine on my iPhone 5 - iOS 6 device.
- I am pushing other view controllers on other parts of my project as well, but this UIViewController seems to be the only issue.
- View controller is pushed on the main thread, and therefore view controller is loaded on the main thread
- During this blocked period, XCode (4.6.1) also gets blocked and does not responds as well

Comment: upgrade your iphone to ios 6 version, or set ios 5 compatibility in your project setting

Comment: instead of 'super' in self = [super initWithNibName:@"CampaignDetailViewController" bundle:nil]; why don't u use 'self' like [self initWithNibName:@"CampaignDetailViewController" bundle:nil];

Comment: @Nagasaki deployment target is set to iOS 5.0. Is there anything else to be set?

Comment: @Ishank that would be pretty much same with what I did, since selfs initWithNibName calls super and returns it, which only means +1 call

Comment: Are you doing this all on the main thread?

Comment: @MikeWeller yes this is all done in the main thread. There are processes that run on other threads, how can we make sure that they are not interfering?

Comment: Did you profile an application? Is there no problems with memory management like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15673536/ipad-ios6-very-long-delay-between-viewwillappear-and-view-appearing-on-the-scre)

Comment: If your nib has some sort of a large image(s) or so...this can be a delaying factor.

Comment: no it does not have any big images, and it gets loaded instantly after the first load of view controller, I guess its related with nib somehow

Comment: Remove the XIB from the project and implement loadView to simply return a new UIView instance, this will confirm if the XIB is the culprit.

Comment: Try pushing the controller with animation set to NO.
Also if you are using core data, try commenting out the line in initWithProduct: where you assign the navigation title.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15673536/ipad-ios6-very-long-delay-between-viewwillappear-and-view-appearing-on-the-scre?lq=1

Comment: this issue is not happening on ipad, and I am not dealing with big image files, or any other big data

Comment: Are you using custom fonts in the new controller's XIB?

Comment: yes I do use custom fonts?

Comment: Do you only use the custom font in this XIB? If so, it might be worth loading it earlier in the app's lifecycle. If not, then its probably not that!

Comment: although it is used in that xib, I use the font in previous xibs (navigation stack-wise) so I guess the font doesn't get loaded for the first time in that xib. :(

Comment: @Bartu, did You solve this problem?? I have a same problem and it is occuring while debugging too. I have no problem with simulators. XCode and app hanging between viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two hints:

1 - is this issue happening on the simulator or on a real device? I've experienced many unexpected delays on the simulator.

2 - remember to call

```
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
```

and

```
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
```

inside the impelentations.

From Apple documentation:

> If you override this method, you must call super at some point in your implementation.

Comment: it happens on real device, and I have added viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear in order to test what is going on, when it started happening these functions were not even added. And yes, super's are added as well, it still hangs

Comment: Ok, I think that there is something wrong with your view. Altough your init method returns fast, when you load a view controller from nib its view is really loaded only at the first view call (probably when the upper navcontroller calls addsubview). To be sure that the slow part is this, override the `loadView` method (implementing only the `[super loadView]` call) and see how much time it needs to execute. If the hang is there, there is something on the view that is slowing down the load (have you ever used instruments?)

Comment: For debugging purposes, you can even avoid calling `[super loadView]` and create an empty view manually in `loadView` method.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when you are executing UI code inside blocks, this should run inside main thread! If you do not you can be affected by this kind of behaviour or worse as UIKit is not thread safe.

```
__weak CurrentViewController *wSelf = self;    
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [wSelf.navigationController pushViewController:wSelf.someController animated:YES];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, i had the same problem and it was quite hidden bug. I had upgraded my project and some .xib files were not upgraded correctly. On interface builded select the .xib and check the project deployment target to be the last one and also opens in to be the default one (mine was stuck on very old version while the rest were updated)!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was with `UILabel` with shadow.